# How to create multiple audio files through audio live streaming chunks through Node JS

Tags: node.js, audio, wav, audio-streaming, node.js-fs

I am **receiving chunks of audio live streaming** and I want to **make multiple audio files by size or specific time**.

I am trying with fs library to create audio files. For simplify my problem I am reading chunks of audio file and making multiple audio files through chunks. Here is my code.

```
fs = require("fs");
// it is file for splitting but in real scenario I am receiving audio live streaming chunks

var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream("bigFile.wav");
let i = 0;
let name = Date.now() + "_audio_";
let filename = name + i + ".wav";
var stream;
myReadStream.on("data", function (chunk) {
    if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
        var stats = fs.statSync(filename)
        var fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
        console.log(`File ${filename} size is ${fileSizeInBytes}`);
        if (fileSizeInBytes >= 500000) {
            stream.end();
            i++;
            filename = name + i + ".wav";
            stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
            stream.on('error', console.error);
           
        }
      
    }
    else {
        stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
        stream.on('error', console.error);
       
    }
    
    stream.write(new Buffer(chunk));
    
});
```

In my code I am facing problem that first split file is working fine but others files are not creating fine but they have data and file size also same as first file.